# Binding Default Interfaces in Assembly, ASP NET vNext Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

in ASP Net 4 with Ninject in order to map interfaces to default classes (i.e IMyClass to MyClass) I could do the following:

```
kernel.Bind(x =>
        {
            x.FromAssemblyContaining<ILibraryMarker>()
             .SelectAllClasses()
             .BindDefaultInterface();
        });
```

I cannot figure out how to do this in ASP NET vNext, since it has its own IoC.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible with ASP.NET 5 DI. You will have to register all services explicitly. Like so:

```
services.AddScoped<ILibraryMarker, LibraryMarker>();
```

Please see https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/322 which might be able to help you.

For historical value, Ninject was included up until beta6 [here](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/tree/f0897c2b26413e9187f6d1bd245a3dce0ac9b0f8/src/Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.Ninject) but has since not been update or released. Perhaps this could be initiative for someone to take over?

I hope this helps.